# Moving a pane in LibreOffice back to the main window

Tags: libreoffice

I accidentally moved a pane in LibreOffice from it's nice docked position to a new window. Now I can't move back it.

[image]

As you can see, the Slide Pane is floating as it's own window and not docked like Tasks, etc.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To move the window back, simply hold the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and double click on any non-button area of the window chrome (not the contents btw).

[image]

Current versions of LibreOffice allow you to drag the Window and it will show a drop target.